# Overlapping chunks in Xarray dataset for Kernel operations

Tags: python, dask, python-xarray, overlap, chunks

I try to run a 9x9 pixel kernel across a large satellite image with a custom filter. One satellite scene has ~ 40 GB and to fit it into my RAM, I'm using `xarray`s options to chunk my dataset with `dask`.

My filter includes a check if the kernel is complete (i.e. not missing data at the edge of the image). In that case a NaN is returned to prevent a potential bias (and I don't really care about the edges). I now realized, that this introduces not only NaNs at the edges of the image (expected behaviour), but also along the edges of each chunk, because the chunks don't overlap. `dask` provides options to create chunks with an [overlap](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/array-overlap.html), but are there any comparable capabilities in `xarray`? I found this [issue](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/3147), but it doesn't seem like there has been any progress in this regard.

Some sample code (shortened version of my original code):

```py
import numpy as np
import numba
import math
import xarray as xr


@numba.jit("f4[:,:](f4[:,:],i4)", nopython = True)
def water_anomaly_filter(input_arr, window_size = 9):
    # check if window size is odd
    if window_size%2 == 0:
        raise ValueError("Window size must be odd!")
    
    # prepare an output array with NaNs and the same dtype as the input
    output_arr = np.zeros_like(input_arr)
    output_arr[:] = np.nan
    
    # calculate how many pixels in x and y direction around the center pixel
    # are in the kernel
    pix_dist = math.floor(window_size/2-0.5)
    
    # create a dummy weight matrix
    weights = np.ones((window_size, window_size))
    
    # get the shape of the input array
    xn,yn = input_arr.shape
    
    # iterate over the x axis
    for x in range(xn):
        # determine limits of the kernel in x direction
        xmin = max(0, x - pix_dist)
        xmax = min(xn, x + pix_dist+1)
        
        # iterate over the y axis
        for y in range(yn):
            # determine limits of the kernel in y direction
            ymin = max(0, y - pix_dist)
            ymax = min(yn, y + pix_dist+1)

            # extract data values inside the kernel
            kernel = input_arr[xmin:xmax, ymin:ymax]
            
            # if the kernel is complete (i.e. not at image edge...) and it
            # is not all NaN
            if kernel.shape == weights.shape and not np.isnan(kernel).all():
                # apply the filter. In this example simply keep the original
                # value
                output_arr[x,y] = input_arr[x,y]
                
    return output_arr

def run_water_anomaly_filter_xr(xds, var_prefix = "band", 
                                window_size = 9):
    
    variables = [x for x in list(xds.variables) if x.startswith(var_prefix)]
    
    for var in variables[:2]:
        xds[var].values = water_anomaly_filter(xds[var].values, 
                                               window_size = window_size)
    
    return xds

def create_test_nc():

    data = np.random.randn(1000, 1000).astype(np.float32)

    rows = np.arange(54, 55, 0.001)
    cols = np.arange(10, 11, 0.001)

    ds = xr.Dataset(
        data_vars=dict(
            band_1=(["x", "y"], data)
        ),
        coords=dict(
            lon=(["x"], rows),
            lat=(["y"], cols),
        ),
        attrs=dict(description="Testdata"),
    )

    ds.to_netcdf("test.nc")

if __name__ == "__main__":

    # if required, create test data
    create_test_nc()
    
    # import data
    with xr.open_dataset("test.nc",
                         chunks = {"x": 50, 
                                   "y": 50},
                         
                         ) as xds:   

        xds_2 = xr.map_blocks(run_water_anomaly_filter_xr, 
                              xds,
                              template = xds).compute()

        xds_2["band_1"][:200,:200].plot()
```

This yields:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKC9l.png)

You can clearly see the rows and columns of NaNs along the edges of each chunk.

I'm happy for any suggestions. I would love to get the overlapping chunks (or any other solution) within `xarray`, but I'm also open for other solutions.

Comment: Xarray doesn't have a `map_overlap` function yet but Dask does: https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.array.map_overlap.html. That may be a good fit for your problem.

Comment: @jhamman Thanks for your suggestion and I already thought about that. However, I'm struggeling with the conversion of a ``xr.DataArra`` into a ``dask.array``. I also didn't found a possibility to import a netCDF-file directly as ``dask.array``. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: If you open the data with `chunks=`, it already wraps dask.arrays - access via the `.data` attribute of a variable.

Comment: Oh yes, you are right! However, if I try to run `map_overlap(water_anomaly_filter, xds["band_1"].data, dtype = np.float32).compute()`
I get a TypeError from `numba` which I don't really understand:
`TypeError: No matching definition for argument type(s) array(float32, 2d, C), omitted(default=9)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Dask's `map_blocks` as follows:

```
arr = dask.array.map_overlap(
    water_anomaly_filter, xds.band_1.data, dtype='f4', depth=4, window_size=9
).compute()
da = xr.DataArray(arr, dims=xds.band_1.dims, coords=xds.band_1.coords)
```

Note that you will likely want to tune `depth` and `window_size` for your specific application.